# WPF, Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown

Tags: wpf, exception

In my WPF C# app, I'm occasionally getting the error: "Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown". The error appears to be occurring in the middle of an OnPropertyChanged event.

Information from the exception:
InnerException is null.
Data is {System.Collections.EmptyReadOnlyDictionaryInternal}

I'm using .Net 4.5.1.

Anyone have any ideas what would be causing this?

```
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        VerifyProperty(propName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            try
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception appears to be thrown during the PropertyChangedEventArgs call.

Here is Verify Property.

```
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void VerifyProperty(string property)
    {
        Type t = this.GetType();

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(property);

        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Property \"{0}\" does not exist in type {1}!", property, t.Name));
    }
```

Comment: how about posting the code in the OnPropertyChanged event?  We can't tell you anything without seeing code.  We're not mind readers.

Comment: What is VerifyProperty? Can it handle a null or incorrect value?

Answer (score 0):

I found some reference to a possible problem with garbage collection causing the System.ExecutionEngineException. I also found several references to .Net bugs causing the exception.

In our code the object that was being updated when the exception occurred was undergoing modifications at the same time. The modification is a single object reference:
                    project.ExtendedData = status.ProjectStatus;
ExtendedData is the property that is being updated when the exception occurred.

I modified the code to disable the update when the object is being modified. This fixed the problem. Before the fix, I was able to reproduce the error 80% of the time.

I'm not sure how I could reference an object that was garbage collected. I thought objects weren't supposed to get garbage collected until there were no references to the object. How can the CLR garbage collect objects that are still in use?